# Como executar um evento uma única vez?

Tags: jquery

Como fazer para que um evento seja disparado uma única vez?

```html
<div>
  <span class="oi">
    OI
  </span>
</div>
```

```js
$('.oi').mouseenter(function(){
    alert('OLÁ');
});
```

Este é apenas um exemplo simples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma solução:

```js
$(function() {

  $('div').on('mouseenter', function() {

      $('h1').html('Mouse Dentro');

    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() {

      $('h1').html('Mouse Fora');
      // Remove os eventos de mouseenter e mouseleave
      // Se você não for realmente fazer nada na saida do mouse
      // Basta utilizar o off dentro da funcão de mouseenter
      $('div').off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');

    });

});
```

```css
div { background: #eee;position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;bottom: 0;right: 0;color: #333;font-size: 28px;text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>Mouse Fora</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu estava procurando obrigado

Answer (score 7):

Recomendo você utilizar o método [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/), já que ele foi desenvolvido justamente para situações como a que você descreveu. Ele dispara o evento para dado elemento apenas uma vez. Após isso o evento é desatado do elemento.

```js
$('.oi').one('click', function(){
    alert('OLÁ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <button class="oi">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

No exemplo acima apenas o primeiro click em `<button>` vai fazer com que o `alert()` seja exibido na tela. Isso porque o evento será automaticamente removido pelo jQuery do elemento após a primeira vez.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica [+1]

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução simples:

```
$('.oi').on('mouseenter', function(){
    alert('OLÁ');
    $('.oi').off('mouseenter');
});
```

Como o método `on` adiciona eventos a um elemento, o `off` remove esses eventos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma variável booleana para saber se é a primeira vez que o evento está sendo disparado e depois setá-lo para false.

```
var primeiravez_mouseenter = true;

$('.oi').mouseenter(function(){
    if(primeiravez_mouseenter)
    {
       alert('OLÁ');
       primeiravez_mouseenter = false;
    }      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, você pode criar uma váriavel global para verificar isso, por exemplo:

```
<script>
   var verifica = true;

   $('.oi').mouseenter(function(){
      if(verifica){
         alert('OLÁ');
         verifica = false;
      }
   });
</script>

<div>
  <span class="oi">
    OI
  </span>
</div>
```